# content access module settings

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I can use "content access module" to make the nodes un accessable to other users. but the issue is i have is the number of users in this is more than 2000 and applying content access manually is a difficult task. so kindly suggest me how to make it automatic so that it should activate at the time of user registration

Comment: Question isn't quite clear, especially this part: "but the issue is i have is the number of users in this is more than 2000 and applying content access manually is a difficult task". Why do you think you have to apply the content access rules manually? What are you trying to achieve exactly? Do those new users belong to certain role?

Comment: Kindly refer the question posted in the below link
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94695/how-do-i-make-the-content-of-one-user-not-accessible-to-other/94739?noredirect=1#94739